# Не показывается фрагмент с картинкой

Tags: android, android-fragment, imageview

Создал два фрагмента один с картинкой другой с кнопками, в Design показывается что есть и картинка и кнопки при запуске приложения в эмуляторе кнопки есть картинки нет.

Разметка фрагмента с кнопками:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                             android:orientation="vertical"
                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                             android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button"/>
<Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Сам код фрагмента:

```
package com.example.leo.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Leo on 17.07.2017.
 */
public class ButtonFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_layout,container,false);
    }
}
```

Разметка фрагмента с картинкой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Код фрагмента с картинкой:

```
package com.example.leo.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Leo on 17.07.2017.
 */
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout,container,false);
    }
}
```

Размета activity main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
                android:name="com.example.leo.myapplication.ButtonFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button_fragment"
                tools:layout="@layout/button_layout"/>

    <fragment
              android:id="@+id/fragment_image"
              android:name="com.example.leo.myapplication.ImageFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              tools:layout="@layout/image_layout"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если изображение векторное то в `build.gradle` добавьте:

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
}
```

`srcCompat` используется для загрузки векторных изображений.

Если изображение не векторное то замените `srcCompat` на `src`:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
```